# Using default with foreignkey model in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm working on a django project where I have 3 models
-category
-subcategory
-product

The subcategory is a foreignkey to the category while the product is a foreignkey to both the category and products

When I run migrations, I get the error:
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'shop_product' with primary key '5' has an invalid foreign key: shop_product.subcategory_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in shop_subcategory.id.`

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='subcategories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'subcategory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'subcategories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, related_name='product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=1)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

**The Terminal Output**

```
python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, coupons, orders, sessions, shop
Running migrations:
  Applying shop.0002_auto_20201103_1603...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/kolawole/Desktop/myshop/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/kolawole/Desktop/myshop/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/kolawole/Desktop/myshop/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/kolawole/Desktop/myshop/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/kolawole/Desktop/myshop/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kolawole/Desktop/myshop/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/kolawole/Desktop/myshop/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/kolawole/Desktop/myshop/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/kolawole/Desktop/myshop/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 229, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "/home/kolawole/Desktop/myshop/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.connection.check_constraints()
  File "/home/kolawole/Desktop/myshop/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 343, in check_constraints
    raise IntegrityError(
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'shop_product' with primary key '5' has an invalid foreign key: shop_product.subcategory_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in shop_subcategory.id.
```

I use python 3.8.5 and django 3.1.2
Any helpful suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined default=1 in Product.subcategory foreignkey options.
It seems that there is no entry in Subcategory with an id equal to 1.
You shoul provide an entry before migrating or change the id to refer to an existing subcategory or remove the default option.